# Unbiased estimator of minimum order statistic

Tags: unbiased-estimator, order-statistics

Let $X_1,X_2$ and $X_3$ be a random sample taken from a continuous population with distribution function F. Consider the function $E(X_{1:3})$ , where $X_{1:3}$ is the minimum order statistic.
Can $$X_1 I(X_1<X_2, X_1<X_3)$$ be the sample based unbiased estimator of the above function?

Comment: Why not compute its expectation?  If you can't see your way to doing that, compute it explicitly in a simple case to see whether it is even plausible.  Barring that, run a quick simulation.  Here is an `R` example with a uniform distribution: `with(data.frame(X=matrix(runif(3*1e4), 3)), mean(X[1,] * (X[1,] < X[2,] & X[1,] < X[3,])))`  The question would be more interesting if you were to multiply your function by $3$ ;-).

Comment: $E(X_1 I(X_1<X_2, X_1<X_3))=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\min(x_2,x_3)}x_1f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)f_{X_3}(x_3)dx_1dx_2dx_3$  Is this expression correct for finding the expectation? Can you give me a complete answer please?

Comment: Just compare events.  For any number $x,$ the indicator of the event $X_{1:3}\le x$ can be partitioned according to which of the $X_i$ is the minimum (because the distribution is continuous, almost surely just one of them is) and therefore $$I(X_{1:3}\le x)=I(X_1\lt X_2,X_1\lt X_3, X_1\le x)+I(X_2\lt X_3,X_2\lt X_1, X_2\le x)+I(X_3\lt X_1,X_3\lt X_2, X_3\le x).$$ This demonstrates that your expression captures only one-third of the integral needed to find the expectation of $X_{1:3}.$

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.